# Python: is index() buggy at all?

Tags: python, indexing

I'm working through this thing on pyschools and it has me mystified.
Here's the code:

```
def convertVector(numbers):
    totes = []
    for i in numbers:
        if i!= 0:
            totes.append((numbers.index(i),i))
    return dict((totes))
```

Its supposed to take a 'sparse vector' as input (ex: `[1, 0, 1 , 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]`)
and return a dict mapping non-zero entries to their index.
so a dict with `0:1`, `2:1`, etc where `x` is the non zero item in the list and `y` is its index.

So for the example number it wants this: `{0: 1, 9: 1, 2: 1, 4: 2, 6: 1}`
but instead gives me this: `{0: 1, 4: 2}` (before its turned to a dict it looks like this:
`[(0, 1), (0, 1), (4, 2), (0, 1), (0, 1)]`

My plan is for `i` to iterate through `numbers`, create a tuple of that number and its index, and then turn that into a dict. The code seems straightforward, I'm at a loss.
It just looks to me like `numbers.index(i)` is not returning the index, but instead returning some other, unsuspected number.

Is my understanding of `index()` defective? Are there known `index` issues?
Any ideas?

Comment: 99.99999% of the time, if you think it's a bug in the language implementation, it's actually your fault.

Comment: 99.9% of statistics are made up on the spot!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

index() only returns the first:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,3]
>>> help(a.index)
Help on built-in function index:

index(...)
    L.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of value.
    Raises ValueError if the value is not present.
```

If you want both the number and the index, you can take advantage of `enumerate`:

```
>>> for i, n in enumerate([10,5,30]):
...     print i,n
... 
0 10
1 5
2 30
```

and modify your code appropriately:

```
def convertVector(numbers):
    totes = []
    for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
        if number != 0:
            totes.append((i, number))
    return dict((totes))
```

which produces

```
>>> convertVector([1, 0, 1 , 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
{0: 1, 9: 1, 2: 1, 4: 2, 6: 1}
```

[Although, as someone pointed out though I can't find it now, it'd be easier to write `totes = {}` and assign to it directly using `totes[i] = number` than go via a list.]

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helps. not sure I understand all the way down, but its something to gnaw on. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do, it could be done in one line:

```
>>> dict((index,num) for index,num in enumerate(numbers) if num != 0)
{0: 1, 2: 1, 4: 2, 6: 1, 9: 1}
```

Comment: +1 For writing what I did. Uh, before I did. Maybe I should read other answers first.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your understanding of `list.index` is incorrect.  It finds the position of the *first* item in the list which compares equal with the argument.

To get the index of the current item, you want to iterate over with `enumerate`:

```
for index, item in enumerate(iterable):
  # blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

index() returns the index of the **first** occurrence of the item in the list. Your list has duplicates which is the cause of your confusion. So index(1) will always return 0. You can't expect it to know which of the many instances of 1 you are looking for.

I would write it like this:

```
totes = {}
for i, num in enumerate(numbers):
     if num != 0:
          totes[i] = num
```

and avoid the intermediate list altogether.

Comment: Okay yeah, so although i advances, its returning the first instance when called, rather than the one I want. That makes sense (although I now thin index night be crap) Thanks to both you guys.

Comment: index is only crap if you want it to do something it's not designed for. It simply could not do what you want it to do. No single function could do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that .index() looks for the first occurence of a certain argument. So for your example it always returns 0 if you run it with argument 1.

You could make use of the built in [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) function like this:

```
for index, value in enumerate(numbers):
    if value != 0:
        totes.append((index, value))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation for index](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is
>   an error if there is no such item.

According to this definition, the following code appends, for each value in `numbers` a tuple made of the value and the first position of this value in the whole list.

```
totes = []
for i in numbers:
    if i!= 0:
        totes.append((numbers.index(i),i))
```

The result in the `totes` list is correct: `[(0, 1), (0, 1), (4, 2), (0, 1), (0, 1)]`.

When turning it into again, again, the result is correct, since for each possible value, you get the position of its first occurrence in the original list.

You would get the result you want using `i` as the index instead:

```
result = {}
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    if numbers[i] != 0:
        result[i] = numbers[i]
```

Comment: @DSM: of course! Thanks. (I think the other suggested solutions with `enumerate` might be better anyway, this might be "clearer" if `enumerate` itself isn't clear.)

Answer (score 0):

Riffing on @DSM:

```
def convertVector(numbers):
    return dict((i, number) for i, number in enumerate(numbers) if number)
```

Or, on re-reading, as @Rik Poggi actually suggests.